# Linqpad how do you use Util.WriteCSV to write datatable to excel using the Beta version of LinqPad

Tags: linqpad

This was my first mortal stab at it

```
Util.WriteCsv<DataTable>(myDataTable, filePath);
```

> The exception i get is 'System.Data.DataTable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Answer (score 6):

It turns out the latest linqpad beta version (v4.44.9) supports datatables in

```
Util.WriteCSV
```

see http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx

In the meantime, if you need to generate csv file for a datatable in older versions, you can follow instructions below:

I ended up writing a custom procedure to do this since it  seems the beta version (4.44.06) is expecting IEnumerable, and even after I put .AsIEnumerable() on myDataTable, it wasn't coming out right:

```c#
public static void ExportToCSV(DataTable table, string filePath)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
  {
    sb.Append(column.ColumnName + ",");
  }

  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
      sb.Append(row[i].ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty) + ",");
    }
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  }

 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString() );
 string.Format("wrote output to {0}", filePath).Dump();

}
```